# Getting name of selected item in Tree UIComponent FLEX 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

This is my second day using FLEX and AS 3.0 so I am very new at this. I am trying to obtain the value of the selected item in a tree component, in this case it is just a name. Below is the tree I have created. The tree contents have been populated programmatically with an array called "cat". The tree gets populated just fine but I can't figure out how to get the name of the currently selected item.

```
<mx:Tree id="category_tree" x="10" y="80" width="160" height="169" showRoot="true" dataProvider="{cat}" labelField="name">
```

I have used the selectedItem.toString() function but this only seems to return the type of object and not the value. Currently it returns "object Object"
In my script I have...

```
category_tree.selectedItem.toString();
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a change event to the tree and have use a callback similar to:

```
 private function changeEvt(event:Event):void {
        var lableData:*;
        var label:String;

        if (event.currentTarget.selectedItem.@data) {
           labelData = event.currentTarget.selectedItem.@data;
        }

        label = event.currentTarget.selectedItem.@label; 
     }
 }
```

or access the value directly

```
category_tree.selectedItem.@label;
```

Comment: When I try category_tree.selectedItem.@label I get an error. ReferenceError: Error #1081: Property label not found on Object and there is no default value.

Comment: check your data that you send to the tree - also, run it in the debugger and see what the values are.  also, try @name - you're last param has the labelField set to name

Comment: I Should have listed that I ran the debugger and tried every name under the sun including the name param. I messed around with it more this morning though and I found the answer, I had to leave the @ symbol off (selectedItem.name). For some reason this was causing the problem. Thank you very much for your help because you did in fact lead me to the correct answer.